# Ubuntu 16.04 Unable to locate package pamusb-tools

Tags: pam

Im trying to install PAM so I can unlock my computer with my usb drive but when I try to install pamusb-tools and libpam-usb, it can't find those pakages. Is there a repository I need to add?

Comment: pamusb-tools and libpam-usb are no longer part of Ubuntu 16.04 .  Take a look at http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/pamusb-tools and http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libpam-usb .  I'm not sure what alternatives are there for you.