# What happened to pamusb-tools and libpam-usb in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, usb, repository, pam

I'm looking into how to make one of my usbs a security key and I found a guide to do so inside Linux here: https://bytevarsity.com/how-to-make-a-usb-security-key/

Two packages that the guide says to install (pamusb-tools & libpam-usb) are nowhere to be found when searching for them. I found previous questions where someone asked the same/similar question in 16.04 ([Ubuntu 16.04 Unable to locate package pamusb-tools](https://askubuntu.com/questions/773975/ubuntu-16-04-unable-to-locate-package-pamusb-tools)), but there weren't any answers and the few suggestions given aren't viable as they pull up effectual 404's.

Did these two packages become deprecated and removed from repo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Packages that loose their maintainer will be removed from newer Ubuntu.

You can find an updated pam-usb on [github](https://github.com/mcdope/pam_usb/). It has a [PPA](https://apt.mcdope.org/).

Warning: 3rd party software is a potential security issue as you need to trust the maintainer.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate that! I wondered if that were the case. PPA you say? I'll keep that in mind as well then.